# append() question - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, memory-management, append, attributeerror

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

from glob import glob

import cv2
import gc
import os
```

It is an attempt to build a CNN to classify lung and colon cancer.
Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrewmvd/lung-and-colon-cancer-histopathological-images

```
path = PATH + 'lung_colon_image_set/lung_image_sets'
classes = os.listdir(path)
```

You will have to define your own PATH to get the data after downloading it from Kaggle.

```
for cat in classes:
    image_dir = f'{path}/{cat}'
    images = os.listdir(image_dir)
    print('Images Count: ', len(images))

IMG_SIZE = 256
```

I have the error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' while I do NOT define any array:

```
X = list()
Y = list()

for i, cat in enumerate(classes):

    images = glob(f'{path}/{cat}/*.jpeg')

    for image in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image)
        #img1 = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
 
        #X = append(X,cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
        #X = np.append(X,cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image), (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
        #X = np.append(X, img1)
        X.append(cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
        Y.append(i)

X = np.asarray(X)

one_hot_encoded_Y = pd.get_dummies(Y).values
```

As you can see, I defined X and Y as lists.

I tried to correct it (you can see commented rows of code), but the loop never ends (images are around 5000).

As per a great comment, cv2.imread(image) creates an array. Thus, I am appending a list (X) with an array (list of arrays). There must be a way to do this, but I do not see it.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 16
     10 img = cv2.imread(image)
     11 #img = img.tolist()
     12 #print(type(img))
     13 #img1 = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
     14 #print(type(img1.shape))
---> 16 X.append(cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
     17 #X = np.append(X,cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image),  (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
     18 #X = np.append(X, img1)
     19 #X=np.append(X, cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
     20 #Y=np.append(i, Y)
     22 Y.append(i)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

EDIT:

Here is the code that addresses the error:

```
for i, cat in enumerate(classes):

    images = glob(f'{path}/{cat}/*.jpeg')

    kk =0 #for tracking only

    for image in images:
    
        kk+=1
        print('kk = ', kk) #tracking
    
        img1 = (cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image), (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))).tolist()

        X.append(img1)
        Y.append(i)
```

It fixes the error and processes normally but it kills the kernel (at about 5000-6000 elements processed out of 15,000).

My guess is extensive memory usage during append() - 3 classes x 5000 images are being added to the list.

How can this be improved?
I can not use extend() because I still need a list (of img1 elements) for that.

using gc() did not work (or maybe I did not use it correctly).

Of course, I can reduce the number of images but I would rather not to.

I use MacOS Pro M1 notebook. No GPU is possible.

Appreciate your ideas!!

Comment: `cv2.imread` returns an array. Please post a full traceback + an actually executable example, otherwise this question is impossible to debug.

Comment: @Megalng - here is the Traceback

Comment: The traceback still proofs that the code you are showing is not the code you are executing. The code you are showing *is not going to produce that error*. Please create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the line,
`X.append(cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))`.

*Option_1:* to check data type of'img' with debugging such as with a print statement

```
for image in images:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    print(type(img))  # Option-1
    X.append(cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
    Y.append(i)
```

*Option_2:* To ensure its np.ndarray or list

```
img = cv2.imread(image)
img = img.tolist()  # Convert numpy ndarray to a list
X.append(cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
Y.append(i)
```

I hope these options will be helpful!

Comment: I tried option 2 but it gives an error:  error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'.  OPTION 1 gives numpy.ndarray. I also uncommented and printed img1 - it is a 'tuple'

Comment: May `img = np.array(img)` be worked instead of `img = np.array(img)` ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
Ultimately I reduced the dataset from 3 x 5000 to 3 x 1500.
I also used random.sample function to randomly select images from all my classes.

The running time for the whole program was about 15 minutes.